# Progress Bar for MuMin Dredge

Tags: r, progress-bar, mixed-models, mumin

I am dredging a model and some of the dredge operations take days and some take hours. I am wondering if I can tell R to give me a progress status while the dredge is running so I know how long to wait.

```
L <- lmer(Fw.FratioFall ~ scale(Average_mintemp_winter) 
          + scale(Average_mintemp_winter^2)
          + scale(percentage_woody_coverage) 
          + scale(percentage_woody_coverage^2)
          + scale(kmRoads.km2) 
          + scale(kmRoads.km2^2) 
          + scale(WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD) 
          + scale(WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD^2) 
          + scale(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi)
          + scale(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi^2) 
          + scale(WT_DEER_springsurveys)
          + scale(WT_DEER_springsurveys^2) 
          + scale(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi)*scale(WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD) 
          + scale(Average_mintemp_winter)*scale(BadlandsCoyote.1000_mi)
          + scale(Average_mintemp_winter)*scale(WELLS_ACTIVEinsideD)
          + year + (year^2) + (year^3) + (1 | YEAR) + (year | StudyArea),  REML = F, data = mydata)


Model1 = dredge(L)
```

The problem with the dredge is that it fills the console up with `singular fit as it produces thousands of models so previous progress bars I have added get lost very quickly. I am wondering if I can get around this.

Thanks `

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the error stream to a file:

```
sink(type = "message", file = "error.log")
```

Do not forget to close the sink afterwards, to display errors and warnings back onto the console:

```
sink(type = "message")
```

Comment: I'm more concerned about % complete than if the dredge has stalled. I havent had any issues with stalling

Comment: In Windows' RGui you normally get a graphical progress bar by default (which is not disrupted by the console messages). What OS you use?

Comment: Just noticed you did not have `trace = 2` argument for `dredge` - this shows up a progress bar.

Comment: I used trace = 2 Kamil but the progress bar appears in the console and quickly gets displaced by all the models.

Comment: Use windows 10!

Comment: Sorry my bad! The model was just running slowly that it took so long to show 1% that I assumed it didn’t work, trace worked perfectly, thanks!